# How can I override a method/attribute after loading a gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm developing a gem that overrides `Pry.config.print` method. This is the code to do that:

```
if !!defined?(::Pry)
  puts 'Working with Pry'

  Pry.config.print = proc do |output, value|
    if value.class.included_modules.include?(::Organizer::Explainer)
      output.puts "#{value.inspect}"
    else
      ::Pry::DEFAULT_PRINT.call(output, value, _pry_)
    end
  end

else
  puts 'Not working with Pry'
end
```

I include my gem in a rails project and, after perform a `rails c`, I can see the message: **"Not working with Pry"**.
Then, I copy/paste the previous code in the console and I can see the message: **"Working with Pry"** and all works well.

So, the problem is that **I need to execute de code after pry was loaded. How can I do this?**

Comment: did you try monkey patching?)

Comment: If your code requires pry before replacing the method, your code will always run after pry has already been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Rails operates lazily in development, so until something has tried to use `Pry` during your `rails console` session, it won't be loaded. It sounds like the first time you run your code, nothing has accessed `Pry`, but by the second time, something has.

To ensure a library is loaded before you try to use or monkeypatch it, especially if you're developing a gem that can be used outside Rails where loads must be more explicit, simply require it. So in this case,

```
require 'pry'
```

You can illustrate this with a clean IRB session:

```
$ irb
2.3.0 :001 > defined?(Pry)
 => nil
2.3.0 :002 > require 'pry'
 => true
2.3.0 :003 > defined?(Pry)
 => "constant"
```